# Does Mr. Morden have a first name?

Tags: babylon-5

In *Babylon 5*, Londo Mollari and others are approached by the mysterious "Mr. Morden". Has a first name ever been revealed for him?

Comment: If you watch the episode, *In the Shadow of Z'ha'dum*, you might see his first name. Look for the scene where Sheridan looks over the list of crew members from the doomed Icarus expedition. One of the crewmembers is Mr. Morden. If you look closely, you might see his name. This is just a hunch since I am writing this from memory and have not seen the episode since it first aired.

Comment: @RichS Good memory! I checked the episode out and his name is simply listed as "Morden". I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe we should say his first name is "Mister" and that his friends regularly contract that to "Mr."

Comment: At this point, there are 6 questions on this website with "Morden" in the title, and several more than mention him. Maybe it is time to give Mr. Morden his own tag.

Comment: @RichS We don't have character tags for any other Babylon 5 character, race, or other aspect, so I feel it's kind of unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In the show, his personal records only list his name as "Morden"

In *The Shadows of Z'ha'dum*, Garibaldi says that his name is "Morden" and Sheridan confirms that he has the same ID as he did on the *Icarus*. The personal records they are looking at only list him with one name:

```
Name     Morden
Species  Human
```

[image: Garibaldi and Sheridan looking at Morden's personal records]

I find it highly unlikely that his personal records, which match his ID for the *Icarus*, would not include his full name. Thus it would appear that Morden only has one name.

### In a spin-off novel, he most likely has a first name, but it is intentionally unrevealed

Jeanne Cavelos [commented on this](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/novels/007.html) when discussing her *Babylon 5* spinoff novel *[The Shadow Within](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/The_Shadow_Within)*.

> Really the thing that gave me the most trouble was when I asked JMS what Morden's first name was. JMS said that he'd never given Morden a first name and that he wasn't really comfortable with the idea of giving one. He'd always thought of Morden as just Morden. This ticked me off for a while, since I figured Morden had to have a first name, and how was I going to present him in informal, social scenes without his first name? I finally thought of a solution to the problem, as you'll see in the book.

It's been a long time since I read the book, but he does have the title of Dr., so they do partly get around it by referring to him as Dr. Morden.

That said, it seems that Morden most likely does have a first name. Although his wife is unnamed, he has a daughter named "Sarah Morden", meaning that Morden is a last name. It seems that JMS prefers to keep the mystery about the character by intentionly not revealing his name.*

Note that JMS has said that this novel is about 90% canon, and that the general story of the Icarus is definitely canon. Cavelos said that her backstory for Morden didn't match JMS' intended backstory, but he didn't ask her to correct it, so information about Morden is ambiguously canon.

<sub>* A similar thing happened in the *Star Wars* universe where for many years, the Emperor was solely known as "Palpatine". The author of the novel *Tarkin* felt that the characters would know him well enough to refer to him by his first name, so the first name "Sheev" was created. A number of fans were unhappy, not only because they thought "Sheev Palpatine" sounded dumb, but they also felt that giving him a first name took away some of the air of mystery about him.</sub>

Comment: The novel, *The Shadow Within*, is also relevant to this question about Mr. Morden's motives as well as his first name. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131781/does-mr-morden-cooperate-with-the-shadows-of-his-own-free-will?rq=1

Comment: *"My big problem came when I asked him Morden's first name. JMS said he had never given Morden a first name. He'd always thought of him just as "Morden." He said he wasn't really comfortable with the idea of him having a first name. That stopped me for a minute. Morden is a major character in my book, and he is part of a fairly small group of archaeologists on the Icarus. It would be difficult to get through the whole book without giving his first name. I found a way around it, as you'll see in the book."* - Same author, slightly different quote. - https://wasser.com/v3i2.htm